# Add and edit data using dialog modal (php mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

How can `id` go to my Modal for edit purposes? I'm using php and have to update data using  dialog modal. How can I achieve this?

```
 <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myLargeModal">   
     <?=$objResult["ID"]; ?>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myLargeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
       aria-hidden="true">         
   <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="ID"  id="ID"  
   minlength="5" required/>

    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="Name"  
    id="Name" required>
  </div>
```

Comment: `How can I achieve this`...achieve what? Please be far more specific when asking questions

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" id="modalIdOpen" data-id="<?php echo $objResult["ID"]; ?>" data-target="#myLargeModal">Open Modal</a>   

  <div class="modal fade" id="myLargeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
       aria-hidden="true">         
   <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="ID"  id="ID"  
   minlength="5" required/>

    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="Name"  
    id="Name" required>
  </div>
```

necessary jquery script

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#modalIdOpen',function(e){
         //process here you can get id using 
         $('#ID').val($(this).data('id')); //and set this id to any hidden field in modal
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: but how data fetch in ID and Name filds

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can put the id in a filed value directly 
  <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myLargeModal"> open it  </a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myLargeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"aria-hidden="true">         
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="<?=$objResult["ID"]; ?>" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="Name"  
    id="Name" required>
  </div>
```